# Qual a arquitetura de pastas adequada para se aplicar a um projeto web?

Tags: front-end, grunt

Meu projeto se resume em páginas em PHP, com pasta para imagens, css, js e fonts.

Já vi que alguns desenvolvedores usam uma pasta para o desenvolvimento do projeto e outra pasta para produção. Gostaria de saber como trabalhar com essas arquiteturas já que estou começando a usar o GRUNT nos meus projetos.

Comment: Respostas baseadas somente em opinões não são boas no stackoverflow, poderia elaborar e deixar mais objetiva sua pergunta. Esse projeto tem algum requisito espcifico? [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486/good-subjective-bad-subjective) e [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) tem algumas recomendações sobre como fazer peguntas

Comment: Dependendo da tecnologia pode haver objetividade, mas sem especificar alguma a pergunta é muito ampla. Por exemplo, se fosse em Java Web eu iria sugerir a estrutura padrão de diretórios do Maven e alguns pacotes básicos baseados em arquiteturas de 3, 4 ou 5 camadas.

Comment: Fiz a alteração na pergunta, vejam se ficou mais claro agora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalmente em qualquer tipo de projeto (PHP, Java, Ruby etc.) você tem uma pasta pública, acessível ao público geral por meio de um servidor web (por exemplo, a pasta `web/` ou a pasta `public/`).

Além dessa pasta, deve-se ter outra pasta com o código-fonte da sua aplicação. É nessa pasta que você organiza os arquivos do seu projeto. Por exemplo, se você estiver criando um projeto com uma arquitetura MVC, seria interessante criar uma pasta `app/` e, dentro dela, as pastas `model/`, `view/` e `controller/`. Evidentemente, essa pasta não é acessível a público geral.

É interessante você baixar um framework para ver como é a estrutura de pastas dentro dele – ou mesmo usar esse próprio framework para seu projeto! No caso do PHP, pode-se usar Zend Framework 2, Symfony 2, Laravel 4, CakePHP, etc. A maioria deles inclusive possui possui um suporte amigável, quase nativo, a GRUNT, ou a ferramentas que você quiser usar separadamente, como LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript, etc.